# How to validate response in Postman?

Tags: rest, postman

I am trying to validate response body including errors in postman. How can I validate the response and text below?

```
{
    "responseHeader": {
        "publisherId": "12345",
        "responseId": "abbcb15d79d54f5dbc473e502e2242c4abbcb15d79d54f5dbc473e502e224264",
        "errors": [
            {
                "errorCode": "1004",
                "errorMessage": "XXXX Not Found"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

These are my tests which are failing:

```
tests['response json contains responseHeader'] = _.has(responseJSON, 'responseHeader');
tests['response json contains errors'] = _.has(responseJSON, 'responseHeader.publisherId');
tests["Response has publisher id"] = responseJSON.publisherId === 10003;
```

Comment: tests['response json contains publisherId'] = _.has(responseJSON, 'responseHeader.publisherId');
tests['response json contains publisherId'] = _.has(responseJSON, 'responseHeader.publisherId');
tests['response json contains errors'] = _.has(responseJSON, 'responseHeader.publisherId.errors');

Answer (score 3):

In the "Test" tab, parse your response body into an object, then use JavaScript to perform your tests.

```
var data = JSON.parse(responseBody);
tests["publisherId is 12345"] = data.responseHeader.publisherId === "12345";
```

Take a look at the test examples at the Postman site:

https://www.getpostman.com/docs/postman/scripts/test_scripts

https://www.getpostman.com/docs/postman/scripts/test_examples

Comment: I tried it but tests are failing   
tests['response json contains responseHeader'] = _.has(responseJSON, 'responseHeader');
tests['response json contains errors'] = _.has(responseJSON, 'responseHeader.publisherId');

tests["Response has publisher id"] = responseJSON.publisherId === 10003;

Comment: I updated the question with your tests. Can you confirm that is how your tests look? How is your `responseJSON` defined?  Did you parse the http response body using `JSON.parse` as in the example?

Comment: this worked tests["Response has publisher id"] = responseJSON.responseHeader.publisherId === "10003";
tests["Response has response id"] = responseJSON.responseHeader.responseId === "abbcb15d79d54f5dbc473e502e2242c4abbcb15d79d54f5dbc473e502e224264"
tests["Response has error code "] = responseJSON.responseHeader.errors[0].errorCode === "10004";
tests["Response has error message"] = responseJSON.responseHeader.errors[0].errorMessage === "Account Not Found";

Comment: now i have a challenge to test these as its failing .... tests['response json contains publisherId'] = _.has(responseJSON, 'responseHeader.publisherId');
tests['response json contains publisherId'] = _.has(responseJSON, 'responseHeader.publisherId');
tests['response json contains errors'] = _.has(responseJSON, 'responseHeader.publisherId.errors');