# Schema validation using Postman

Tags: postman

My response looks like this as below:-

```
{
    "Header": {
        "MessageId": "11",
        "From": "user1 (user2@domain1.org)",
        "To": ["user2 (user1@domain2.org)"],
        "Cc": [],
        "Bcc": [],
        "Subject": "FW: Send a mail with normal text file base64 encoded",
        "BodyText": "Me to Me concept super",,
        "Direction": 2,
        "SystemDateTime": "2004-10-10T10:55:03.487",
        "InstanceId": "tecf32af-db97-49eb-a3e3-73952c923401",
        "HasAttachment": false
    },
    "Attachments": []
}
```

I want to know how to validate the schema of my response using the postman tool

Comment: this was asked just 2 weeks ago https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46498749/how-to-validate-response-in-postman. and there are lots of links available from postman blog and docs. [1](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/postman/scripts/test_examples), [2](http://blog.getpostman.com/2017/07/28/api-testing-tips-from-a-postman-professional/), [3](http://blog.getpostman.com/2014/04/17/how-to-write-automated-tests-for-apis-with-postman-part-2/)

Answer (score 3):

Use `tv4` available in the Postman sandbox to do schema validation of the JSON response. Read more at [Postman Tip 4](http://blog.getpostman.com/2017/07/28/api-testing-tips-from-a-postman-professional/).

If you do not have a JSON Schema defined for your response, you can write one by hand, or generate one based on the response you have using one of the many tools available online to generate JSON schemas.

Comment: please mention your favourite tool to autogenerate the schema

Comment: @DilipAgheda you can use this tool to generate JSON schema - https://jsonschema.net/