# Are there ways to check the structure of JSON response in Postman tests?

Tags: automated-tests, postman

I have written several tests in Postman, based on the example snippet codes given in the Postman GUI on Windows desktop.

Mainly, I want to check for existence of the parameters in the response (exact in those cases where I need to check for particular values of the parameters) and I want to know if there's a better way to do it than the way I've been doing now.

The following test shows one such example and this is just a small part of it. The actual response schema is a lot larger so I envisioned writing 50-60 lines of such checks per API endpoint.

```
pm.test("Det details of a POI", function () {
    pm.expect(jsonData.code).to.eql(0);
    pm.expect(jsonData.data[0].provider).to.eql("google");
    pm.expect(jsonData.data[0]).to.have.property("id");
    pm.expect(jsonData.data[0].location).to.have.property("position");
    pm.expect(jsonData.data[0].location.address).to.have.property("text");
    pm.expect(jsonData.data[0].location.address).to.have.property("house");
    pm.expect(jsonData.data[0].location.address).to.have.property("street");
    pm.expect(jsonData.data[0].location.address).to.have.property("postalCode");
    pm.expect(jsonData.data[0].location.address).to.have.property("city");
    pm.expect(jsonData.data[0].location.address).to.have.property("county");
    pm.expect(jsonData.data[0].location.address).to.have.property("state");
    pm.expect(jsonData.data[0].location.address.country).to.eql("United Kingdom");
    pm.expect(jsonData.data[0].location.address).to.have.property("countryCode");
    pm.expect(jsonData.data[0].contacts).to.have.property("phone");
    pm.expect(jsonData.data[0].contacts.website.value).to.include("www.google.com");
    pm.expect(jsonData.data[0].contacts.website).to.have.property("label");
    pm.expect(jsonData.data[0].categories[0]).to.have.property("id");
    pm.expect(jsonData.data[0].categories[0]).to.have.property("title");
    pm.expect(jsonData.data[0].categories[0]).to.have.property("type");
    pm.expect(jsonData.data[0].categories[0]).to.have.property("system");
)};
```

Any tips and improvements would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You might want to take a look at this as it come built-in to the native Postman app - https://github.com/epoberezkin/ajv

Answer (score 0):

You're basically asking the same as these two Stack Overflow posts:

- [Schema validation using Postman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46710260/schema-validation-using-postman)
- [How to validate response in Postman?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46498749/how-to-validate-response-in-postman)

Answer: There is a json format validation build into Postman it uses the [Tiny Validator](https://geraintluff.github.io/tv4/) project to allow schema validation in post-request test scripts. Research Postman's documentation ([1](https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/scripts/test_examples/), [2](https://blog.getpostman.com/2017/07/28/api-testing-tips-from-a-postman-professional/)) for examples on how to use it.