# Postman: How can I validate decimal data?

Tags: javascript, postman, dataformat

How can I validate a data format.

I have the response body:

```
 "value": [
    {
        "cotacaoCompra": 4.08520,
        "cotacaoVenda": 4.08580,
        "dataHoraCotacao": "2019-10-22 13:10:34.471"
    }
]
```

I need to validate that "cotacaoCompra" has 4 the format "0.0000"

How can I do it with Postman?

Please help me.

Comment: look into regular expressions

Comment: I'm trying but apparently postman is not recognizing regex. It's reading regular expession like a string

Comment: Does that answer your question? [How to validate response in Postman?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46498749/how-to-validate-response-in-postman)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to validate response in Postman?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46498749/how-to-validate-response-in-postman)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the .match() function from the chai assertion library and use regex to check the format:

```
let jsonData = pm.response.json();
pm.test("Check value is correct", () => {
   pm.expect(jsonData.value[0].cotacaoCompra).to.match(/\d{1}.\d{5}/);
});
```